# How to implement a LinkedList from scratch that only accepts String Value?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am new to data structure and now want to implement a LinkedList from scratch  that only accepts String values. How should i do it?

Comment: see this:http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-singly-linked-list/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I am not providing you with the code but a few tips  which should help you get started.
Structure of a linked list is usually like
nd1 -> nd2 -> nd3-> null, where nd is a node.
a. Create a Node class with attributes String value, Node next. Thus it would look like.

```
class Node{
String value;//place holder for your String
Node next;//pointer to your next node.
}
```

b. To add a new node, you need following method addNode(Node nd) .You will need to iterate till the last node of your list and add the nd after that. i.e last.next=nd;
Similarly you can go ahead and implemene tyour own methods.